# paper.js handlers not working

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, paperjs

I have a JavaScript file:

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = 'canvas1';
    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400;
    canvas.resize;

    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = '/text/javascript/';
    e.src = '/static/notebook/js/paper.js';

    var c = document.createElement('script');
    c.type = '/text/javascript/';
    c.src = '/static/notebook/js/mypaper.js';
```

My mypaper.js file has the following function that is built into paper.js:

```
var d = document.getElementById('canvas1');
paper.setup(d);
function onFrame(event) {   //this function does not run 
console.log("test");        
}
var raster = new paper.Raster('/static/notebook/js/turtle.png'); //this works?
```

but it does not run. I also noticed onkeydown does not work. I believe this has something to do with the PaperScope but I am unsure. I can create rasters, paths and lines, they all display fine, except the functions don't run. I am trying to get it to animate in IPython Notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to call call paper.js with

```
c.type="text/paperscript";
```

and see if this helps. Or execute your code with [PaperScript.execute(code, scope)](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscript/#execute-code-scope)

Comment: I had to change my function from function onFrame(event) to paper.onFrame = function (event)